# How to generate a mp4(not a avi) file from a number of frames using Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I am unable to generate a mp4 file from a number of frames, although I can generate avi file. How to get mp4 file instead of avi file

```
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object.The output is stored in 'outpy.avi' file.
import cv2
out = cv2.VideoWriter('outpy.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 10, (frame_width,frame_height))
out.write(frame) 
out.release()
```

Comment: What's your error mesage your are getting?

Comment: I want to save it in mp4 format .. but its getting generated only in avi..

Comment: That's not your full code, what is frame? is it a numpy array? You can quickly try `VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')` and make sure file ending is mp4

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mpeg')` or `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')`.

---

Here is an example:

```
sz = (640, 480)
fps = 20
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', 'e', 'g')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mpeg')

## open and set props
vout = cv2.VideoWriter()
vout.open('output.mp4',fourcc,fps,sz,True)
```

---

Full description at this answer: [How can I write a series of images into a video using opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200064/how-can-i-write-a-series-of-images-into-a-video-using-opencv/48200116#48200116)